# Решите задачу по python!

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]прошу решить задачу изложенную в скриншоте во вложении
заранее благодарю

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ссылка в гугле.

Советую немного гуглить самому свои вопросы.

```
print(type(n))
print(type(s))
```

Comment: минус за ответ на вопрос, нарушающий правила сайта